# Executing code immediately after jQuery-handlebars plugin finishes running

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, promise

I use [jQuery-handlebars](https://github.com/71104/jquery-handlebars) to load a handlebars template and then call the `jQuery-responsiveTabs` plugin to create a tabbed interface like this:

```
$("#tabs-test").render('tabs',data);
console.log("The render method has finished");
$("#horizontalTab").responsiveTabs({
   rotate: false,
   startCollapsed: 'tabs',
   collapsible: 'tabs',
   setHash: true,
   disabled: [3,4],
   activate: function(e, tab) {
     $('.info').html('Tab <strong>' + tab.id + '</strong> activated!');
  }
});
```

The console looks like this:

```
  XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/templates/data/tabs.json". 
  The render method has finished (index):139
  XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/templates/tabs.hbs".
```

How do I ensure that I can execute code immediately after the render method finishes executing?

## EDIT:

Tried using `jQuery`'s `promise` and `when` methods to resolve this:

```
 var handlebars_promise=$("#tabs-test").render('tabs',data).promise();
                    $.when(handlebars_promise).then(function(){
                        $("#horizontalTab").responsiveTabs({
                        rotate: false,
                        startCollapsed: 'tabs',
                        collapsible: 'tabs',
                        setHash: true,
                        disabled: [3,4],
                        activate: function(e, tab) {
                            $('.info').html('Tab <strong>' + tab.id + '</strong> activated!');
                        }
                    });
                    console.log(handlebars_promise.state());    
                });
```

This is the log:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/templates/data/tabs.json". 
resolved (index):140
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/templates/tabs.hbs".
```

The promise is resolved before the operation is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin doesn't specify any callbacks, you need to hook the function that initializes the plugin. for example,

```
var saveFunc = $.fn.render;
$.fn.render = function(template, source){
    saveFunc(template, source);
    //your code here
};
```

another option is to directly edit the source code to call the function you want at the point where you want. ich you don't want to directly put your code into the hook code, you need to add a new callback in a hook.

example:

```
var saveFunc = $.fn.render;
$.fn.render = function(template, source, callback){
    saveFunc(template, source);

    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
       callback.call(this);
    }
};

$("#tabs-test").render('tabs',data,function(){
    //your code here
});
```

...since i don't know the source, this might also fail, regarding ajax calls. if you have to be sure the render function is done when calling your callback, you will have to modify the source to implement a callback that is fired when everything is loaded...

the only other option would be to use setInterval and check if the content is loaded (which wouldn't be a clean approach....)